# Ensure of execution a function in server side by my function in client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am designing a website with Javascript and Asp.net. I have a lot of functions in client side (i.e in my html code) and I call my server side functions using a webservice.

How can I ensure that the function in server side is executed by my client function?

I don't want someone execute my server side code by his function. For example he can copy my client side codes to his own page and execute that.

Can I use session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AJAX? Tell Javascript to hit a specific end point on your server, which will trigger that function.

Comment: yes i am using ajax.how can i tell javascript to hit a specific end point on your server?

Comment: Use the URL. The server needs to know how to respond to the URL through routing.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the servercode that is called, check the session. If it's a new session, without some specific value that *your* code previously should have put into it, the code may have been called by client code in some other site. React accordingly.